# viewContentLoaded - Without duplicating code per each controller - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hey all I'm trying to get a feel for angular and have ran into a little snag.

I have a container structure like the following:

```
<div class="main-container" ng-view>
    <!-- The below divs are constantly being 
         reloaded based on the current URL and it's associated view -->
    <div class="left-col">
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
    </div>
</div>
```

Before I implemented Angular I just had a simple script that would check the height of the window and set the height of the left column and right column divs accordingly.

With angular there is probably a better way to do this then attaching an event function to the window object. Basically I want to fire a function everytime a new view is rendered but not duplicate the below code in all of my angular controllers like so:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', setColumnHeight);
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this problem in my app by having a root "Application Controller" at the top of the DOM tree. For example:

```
<body ng-controller='applicationController'>
...
<div class="ng-view"></div>
...
</body>
```

applicationController is always there, and can set up bindings on its scope when it is created.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting that event listener on the root scope:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', setColumnHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
<div class="main-container" ng-view>
    {{ setColumnHeight() }}
    <!-- The below divs are constantly being 
         reloaded based on the current URL and it's associated view -->
    <div class="left-col">
    </div>
    <div class="right-col">
    </div>
</div>
```

and it will check the height every time a render is made, however, this seems to be a bit over processing.

The best approach would be to only update the height from both columns when the height of one of them changes. For that you could use [DOM Mutation Observers](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutation-observers), however they are not yet available on all browsers. If that's not a problem for you, check the [mutation-summary lib](https://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/).

If you are using jQuery you can also try this: https://github.com/jqui-dot-net/jQuery-mutate (examples [here](http://www.jqui.net/jquery-projects/jquery-mutate-official/)).